# Atmosphere + GWT + Spring Security integration issue

Tags: java, spring, gwt, web.xml, atmosphere

I have gwt app with spring sequrity for gwt (gwt-sl). I would like to implement atmosphere20. This is my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>gwt</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gwt</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MY_APP/rpc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>init</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MY_APP.shared.util.BootstrapValidationServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!--then follow all GWT Services with mappings and my listeners-->

<servlet>
    <description>AtmosphereServlet</description>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>MY_APP.atmosphere</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AtmosphereServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MY_APP/atmosphere/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

1) there are related topics with Atmosphere and Spring Security integration. but no answers. More over I need both atmosphere and plain rpc for gwt (both secured).
Works either Atmosphere or Spring Security.

I have following errors:
streaming:

```
org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor - Invalid request state. AsyncContext#startAsync not supported. Make sure async-supported is set to true in web.xml http://<path>/atmosphere/rpc
501 - GET /<path>/atmosphere/rpc?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.2.4-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=streaming&Content-Type=text%2Fx-gwt-rpc%3B%20charset%3DUTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true&_=1411453107109 (<path>)
   Request headers
      Host: <path>
      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
      Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
      Content-Type: text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8
      Referer: http://<path>/Page.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
      Cookie: JSESSIONID=1te41te8axqfe8cqydbnpsie3
      Connection: keep-alive
   Response headers
      X-Atmosphere-first-request: true
      X-Atmosphere-tracking-id: 7eae0ee2-5fdc-4a51-9ebc-614094e67244
      X-Atmosphere-error: AsyncContext not enabled
```

websocket:

```
org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor - Invalid request state. AsyncContext#startAsync not supported. Make sure async-supported is set to true in web.xml http://<path>/atmosphere/rpc
org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol - Status code higher or equal than 400. Unable to deliver the websocket messages to installed component. Status 501 Message OK
```

Please help with configurations. Best solution is to add Spring Security to the existence gwt-rpc examples for atmosphere

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue with gwt 2.6 and atmosphere-gwt-2.2.0 and atmosphere client 2.2.5.
I've added `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` to a spring security filter and it seems to work.

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
  </filter>
```

Comment: It is not solution for me. For sure I added it. After sending on client from server my Spring Session is removed from HttpSession. to solve this I added listener on send and all the time rewrite SpringContext. it works but look like is not best solution